# My values are not nil, but Getting Thread 1: Fatal Error

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

[image: App crash error]

From the above image, I am getting this Thread 1: Fatal Error message. I know what this error message is which is why I am guard checking each value before I assign it. In the debug console, all of my values are not nil, which is why I am confuse on why I am getting this error.

What I am doing here is selecting a cell from a table view in a previous VC, and passing that info to a new VC where I am setting those values to the var facility. I have done the passing of my info correctly since the values are not nil. I am assigning these values to Outlets, which I have checked to see if their connections are okay and they are.

I'm just not sure how I can be getting this error if my values are not nil and my Outlets are connected correctly.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: *"my values are not nil and my Outlets are connected correctly"* – Add `print(self.facilityName)` and `print(courtName)` to your code to verify your assumptions.

Comment: My print(courtName) displays a value, but my print(self.facilityName) displays "none". Is it because I am trying to assign the value to the outlet in the didSet?

Comment: That probably means that the facilityName outlet is *not* properly connected.

Comment: I've checked, and it is. I even disconnected it and reconnected it.

Comment: Did you see if the Label it's available? It's possible that label is null! If like that, you can make the property how a Lazy. To try it quickly, you comment the error line, and the error should persist on next assign

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix it just by changing `self.facilityName.text = courtname` into `self.facilityName?.text = courtname`. Adding a `?` is important because `self.facilityName.text` started off with `nil`.

Also, remember to include an `@IBOutlet weak var facilityName: UILabel!`

Comment: Do you mind sending the whole code or the main parts so that I could look over it?